# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: list, python-3.x

```
import random
l = []
for i in range(0,8):
        key = random.randrange(33,126)
        key = chr(key)
        l.append(key)
print(" ".join(l))
x = (round(sum([ord(c) for c in l]) / 8) - 32)
print(x)
if l[i]:
        [ord(c) for c in x]
```

this is what gets printed:

J F P @ F n o ,

46

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Sweg\g.py", line 11, in 
    print([ord(c) for c in x])
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

I to convert the whatever is inside of 'x' to its equivalent ASCII code

Comment: Can you please add the full error message? It shows the line number. Also, hit Ctrl+K to format code.

Comment: `..for c in x` is wrong, because x is an int. This is what the error message is saying. Please read through some of the related questions.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? The last line `[ord(c) for c in x]` does not make any sense at all.

Comment: its supposed to turn the variable 'x' back into an equivalent ASCII code

Comment: If `x` is just an int though, why are you trying to iterator over it? Why not just `ord(x) `?

Answer (score 0):

`x` is an `int` (not iterable) so `[ord(c) for c in x]` shows the error you get because you can't iterate the `for` loop.

As I don't know what you want to get I can't provide a better solution.

Comment: basically i want it to turn the variable 'x' back into an equivalent ASCII code, is that possible?

Comment: Can you edit your question an explain clearly what you want to do with your code?